# Extjs 4.1 - How to copy Listeners from Object A to Object B

Tags: javascript, extjs, listeners, event-listener

Anyone knows how to copy listeners from Object to another?

I tried

```
    Object a,b (pre-created...) 
    b.events = a.events
    b.hasListeners = a.hasListeners
```

But it didnt worked as i expanded **Object b** it didnt stop in the breakpoint i had in the function i had listening for expand, is there any "good way" of doing it?

Comment: Are both objects similar.For example you have grid obj vs. Panel object and if you copy grid's itemclick event to panel,it wont work.So are you doing it right ?

Comment: Object a, is a treenode, and b is also a treenode...
Soo yes, i think i am doing that right :X

Comment: What do you mean by TreeNode, what class is it? Something that implements NodeInterface?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli
Yes sorry, equivalent to NodeInterface
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't directly link ExtJS-generated object hierarchy subtrees into other objects; it's bad style and can result in all kind of problems, like memory leaks or premature destruction.

E.g. if one object is destroyed, but the other lives on, what happens to the shared events object?

It may or may not be destroyed by the destructor, and then the other object tries to access it, which results in undefined behaviour.

If you need the same listeners on multiple objects, you should create a prototype that you derive these objects from, or a function that adds exactly these listener functions to whatever object you provide as a parameter.

For your example, because nodes can be auto-created by a reader, I would use the second approach, adding the function on the store that contains the nodes:

```
addListenersToTreeNode: function(node) {
    node.on('collapse', this.onCollapse);
    node.on('expand', this.onExpand);
    node.on('example', this.onExample);
}
```

then call the function on both nodes:

```
nodeStore.addListenersToTreeNode(a);
nodeStore.addListenersToTreeNode(b);
```

and voilá, the tree nodes now have the same listeners.

Comment: But what if you added dinamically listeners to A... and you don't know what do listeners does it have? How can you re-add it dinamically to B ?

Answer (score 0):

define your code in class.
Ext.define('appname.myapp.formname.form',{
xtype:'anyname',
listeners:{
click........
keyup.....
}
});
use your xtype where you